# How to display JS string value (dynamic data) in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to display the first value of Port01 in Html. The corresponding JavaScript code for this.

```
<script>


function loadFile(filePath) {
    var result = null;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", filePath, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
            result = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    return result;
  };


var inputData = loadFile("data123.js");
var sensorData = JSON.parse(inputData);
var valueData = sensorData[0].value;
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = valueData;
</script>

<body>
    <div id="value" ></div>
</body>
```

and in addition data123.js file

```
[{"name":"VVB001 (port01)","time":"2021-02-10 14:01:09","type":"a-Peak","value":0.2},{"name":"VVB001 (port02)","time":"2021-02-10 14:01:09","type":"a-Peak","value":0.2},{"name":"VVB001 (port03)","time":"2021-02-10 14:01:09","type":"a-Peak","value":0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the following line:

```
result = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

gets executed before the response arrives. This is because of the asynchronous nature of the call, which you set with `false` in `xmlhttp.send()`. You should wrap the above line in an `onreadystatechange` listener:

```
function loadFile(filePath) {
  var result = null;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", filePath, false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      result = xmlhttp.responseText;
      return result;
    }
  };
};

var inputData = loadFile("data123.js");
var sensorData = JSON.parse(inputData);
var valueData = sensorData[0].value;
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = valueData;
```

A side note: your JSON file has a .js extension.

Comment: Then the JSON you are getting is invalid, as opposed to that you've posted in your question, which is valid.

Comment: other ideas maybe?

Comment: This is what can be deduced from your error.